# Not able to run Electron app inside azure VM

Tags: windows, electron, azure-vm-templates

I have packaged electron app for windows platform, it works as expected in local machine but I try to same app in azure VM( same OS), it shows only blank screen and disappears. I am not sure, why same app works in local machine and not in VM having same OS.[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuhww.png)

If any of you had similiar issue, please help me

Note :This is single core processor

Answer (score 0):

Main window(main.js) was being  maximized (tried to)  before it was rendered, this is because, asynchronous way of working. Either by setting timeout or commenting the functionality that maximizes the window, resolved this bug.

The VM was single core machine.

```
 mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', ()=>{
    mainWindow.maximize();
 })
```